# Use of undeclared identifier for "nil"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null, beta, undeclared-identifier

I have just replaced all `NULL` references to `nil` in one of my code folders. But it looks like something went clearly wrong. It now shows up "Use of undeclared identifier" error for every `nil` in code.

I have cleaned Derived Data folder.
Restarted xCode.
Cleaned caches and tried rebuilding many times.
Can someone please explain what is going wrong.

P.S.: Using xCode 7.0 beta 4 on OSX El Capitan Beta.

Edit 1: Maybe screenshot helps: [image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

`nil` is only appropriate for object pointers in Objective-C or Objective-C++ code. It is not appropriate for non-object pointers or in non-Objective-C(++) code. For those, you should use `NULL` or `nullptr`.

(In Objective-C(++), you should use `Nil` with a capital "N" for *class* pointers.)

Comment: Yes, i know that. But the issue is that the entire code is in objective-c. And after that text replacement it is not only not building the main target (where the changes where made), but also sub targets of CocoaPods project in workspace. What can it be? How to fix it?

Comment: You don't quote the error verbatim and completely in your question. Was there something that `#define`d `NULL` that you've now unintentionally changed to `#define` `nil` or something like that? Did something `#undef` `NULL` and now it's `#undef`-ing `nil`?

Comment: I remember NULL is macros, so I checked it.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how it looks. Maybe it will help you in helping me)

Comment: Can you please share the text in following file: Simulator iOS9 -> usr/include -> MacTypes.h. I have an error there in line 89.